# Xamarin VS Flutter

Tags: flutter, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was reading on the net and I was training a little. I am developing an app with Xamarin but too many problems, endless crashes and very slow builds. Looking for alternatives, I came across Flutter, which has a good reputation (I don't know, I've ever used Flutter) compared to what aspects is one better than the other? And is there any way to import a Xamarin.ios project to flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your requirements and your skill set. If you have experience in .Net development and you have knowledge of c# you can go with Xamarin. You will find it more similar.

But if you are beginner and your aim is to learn new technologies then defiantly you should go with Flutter and dart. As it have better performance and Hot Loading features which are not that good in Xamarin.

Also xamarin is coming with new updates you must be aware of it, i.e. .Net MAUI the extended version of xamarin forms. So in that also you have to learn new things and adopt it.

> There is not way to directly import your Xamarin.iOS project into
> Flutter as of now, you have to migrate it manually.

For more information you can read some articles which are available on simple google search, here are some useful links:

- https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-vs-xamarin-a-developer-s-perspective/
- https://blog.logrocket.com/xamarin-vs-flutter/

Comment: `As it have better performance and Hot Loading features which are not that good in Xamarin.` agree

Comment: Just checked the video of james montemagno about .net maui preview 8 on youtube. In that hot reload is working like charm. Let's wait and see how it goes.